# Send SMS with AWS Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send an SMS with the AWS javascript sdk with a verification code.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var sns = new AWS.SNS();

var params = {
  Message: 'this is a test message',
  MessageStructure: 'string',
  PhoneNumber: '+12346759845'
};

sns.publish(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I keep getting "Unexpected key \'PhoneNumber\' found in params".

I have followed the examples in the documentation and it seems what I have is valid as far as I can tell. Apparently, I do not need to create a topic to send individual text messages.

Comment: The code looks correct. Are you perhaps using an old version of the AWS SDK?

Comment: @user3345171 Should that AWS.SNS(); be AmazonSNSClient(); ?

Comment: @error2007s no, this is JavaScript, you seem to be trying to convert it to Java.

Comment: That was it Mark. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm having the same problem, any luck finding a solution yet?

Comment: The solution was as Mark said. I was using an older version of the AWS SDK for node.

Comment: @user3345171 what version did you end up using?  I've tried not setting the version and also setting it to '2010-03-31' - both times I get the error about Unexpected key 'PhoneNumber' found in params.  Can you update your question with the correct code?  Or did you have to do something specific on the console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes so the correct answer is that an outdated sdk version was used. 
To fix it set aws-sdk to * in your package.json file and run

npm install aws-sdk

With the latest version this code will run fine!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Its because AWS SNS is supported only on certain regions. This link lists the supported regions -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_supported-countries.html